# Visual studio 2019 - copying a name from the macro screen

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to add a macro that was defined in an external property file.
I hope I'm not missing anything obvious, but I can't find a way to copy the macro name so I can paste it.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Right click on project -> properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories
2. Expend the macro menu
3. Choose any macro name and try to copy it to the included directories list

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.4
[image: Additional include dirs window]

Is there a shortcut to copy the macro name? is there a way to define one?